# How do Aimbots get detected?

Tags: first-person-shooter, anti-cheat, aiming

I was wondering on the programming methods which are used to detect when a player is using an Aimbot/AutoAim cheat.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a legit question.

Comment: See also [Prevent Multiplayer Cheating](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33922/prevent-multiplayer-cheating) and its duplicates: [How do I avoid users hacking my network games from the client side?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140592/how-do-i-avoid-users-hacking-my-network-games-from-the-client-side) and [How can a web game store points online without giving the user the possibility to do the same call but with more points?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60872/how-can-a-web-game-store-points-online-without-giving-the-user-the-possibility-t)

Comment: @Charanor "This question does not show any research effort" seems applicable in this situation.

Comment: Way way too broad. There are so many different things that can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most games allow you to manually spawn an invisible bot, and a lot of aimbots don't filter these out.

By spawning 3 different bots and checking if the user aims at them, you can check whether they have aimbot or not.

Comment: Answering questions that are too broad only encourages them to keep doing it. This is only one tiny piece of the puzzle and doesn't "answer the question".

Comment: @Almo If you look at the upvote-downvote ratio on the question, then you'll see that people can't really decide whether it's ontopic or offtopic

Comment: It's clearly off-topic. Too broad. How many possible answers does this thing have?

Comment: @Almo Being off-topic or too broad is **not** determined by how many answers it (potentially) has. For example *"give me all examples of pathfinding algorithms"* is much broader than *"give me one example of a pathfinding algorithm"* even though they theoretically have the exact same amount of answers. Being too broad is related to how much the question is asking for. There's a discussion about this somewhere on meta but I can't find it now since I'm on mobile.

Comment: But giving answers to off topic questions tells new users that these off-topic questions are ok.